# Programmatically Make "$this->form_validation->run()" Return false

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation

My goal involves two steps

**Step 1**

- First check for empty `username` AND `password` values
- If empty, return back to the login form stating that empty values
  were found

**Step 2**

- No empty values found, so check if the login is valid by querying the database
- If valid, proceed to dashboard
- If not, return back to login form stating that the login failed

For the above scenario, my controller code is as follows:

### Controller

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('userid', 'Username', 'trim|required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required');
if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
{
    $this->load->view('login'); // this works fine if either of one is empty
}
else
{
    // I query the database and check if valid or not
    if(<not_valid>)
    {
       // but how to pass the "Login Failed" message in this code block?
       /* I'm assuming that if I somehow make "$this->form_validation->run()" 
          return false, then the message can be passed to the view */
       $this->load->view('login');
    }
    else
    {
        $this->load->view('dashboard');
    }
}
```

### HTML

```
echo validation_errors();
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="userid" class="control-label">Enter User ID</label>
    <input type="text" id="userid" name="userid" 
       value="<?php echo set_value('userid'); ?>" class="form-control" 
       placeholder="Email Address"/>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="password" class="control-label">Enter Password</label>
    <input type="password" id="password" name="password" class="form-control" 
       placeholder="Secret Password"/>
</div>
```

### PS

I'm aware of callbacks but how would I fire a single callback for two fields (username and password)? If I do:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('userid', 'Username', 'callback_check_valid');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'callback_check_valid');
```

would it mean that I'll have to manually check for emptiness of both fields on my own? Something like this:?

```
public function check_valid($un, $pw)
{
    if(trim($un) == '' || trim($pw) == '')
    {
       return false;    
    }
    else
    {
        // check for valid login
    }
}
```

Comment: You will need to alter your logic, it seems that codeigniters callbacks are unable to send 2 parameters... but you can use `$_POST` ;)

Comment: @Kyslik As it turns out, I'm able to send two parameters to the callback function `check_valid()` :)

Answer (score 0):

```
public function check_valid() {
    $un = $_POST['username'];
    $pw = $_POST['password'];
    if(trim($un) == '' || trim($pw) == '') {
        return false; 
    } else {
        // check for valid login
    }
}
```

try this logic

Comment: I'm familiar with this part. I guess you missed out the part where I specified that I'm not sure on how to pass an error message in case login check fails.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if($this->input->post()){
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('userid', 'Username', 'trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required');

    if ($this->form_validation->run()){
        $username = $this->input->post('userid');
        $password = $this->input->post('password');

        if($this->check_valid($username, $password)){
            $this->load->view('dashboard');
        }else{
            $this->load->view('login');
        }
    }else{
        $this->load->view('login');
    }
}
```

This is similar how I do my login checks with codeigniter.

You can left second trim check away from check_valid function, values are already trimmed.

Comment: But how would you pass an error message to the `login` view in case $this->check_valid() returns false?

Comment: Using flashdata is good way. https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html